# How to check of a column in a data frame equals a certain data type in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to convert all my columns that are of the data type objects into strings.

For simplicity, here is the column headers:

```
keys= [Name, Age, Passport, Date, Location, Height]
```

'Name' and 'Location' are of type object. I need to identify these columns are of type object, and convert the columns into strings.

My loop that I attempted to write:

```
while variable_1 < len(keys):
  if df[variable_1].dtypes == object:
    df[variable_1] = df[variable_1].astype(str)
    variable_1 = variable_1 + 1
```

This is throwing an obvious error, I am sort of stuck on the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=[1, 2, 3],
        B=[[1], [2], [3]],
        C=['1', '2', '3'],
        D=[1., 2., 3.]))
```

Use `applymap` with `type` to see the types of each element.

```
df.applymap(type)

               A               B              C                D
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
2  <class 'int'>  <class 'list'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
```

Using `select_dytpes` to take just `object` columns and `update` to update the dataframe

```
df.update(df.select_dtypes(include=[np.object]).astype(str))

df.applymap(type)

               A              B              C                D
0  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
1  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
2  <class 'int'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'float'>
```

Comment: This seems to be working, but when I print this command 'print(df.Name.dtypes)' it still comes out as an object. But I did get exactly what I wanted when I printed the 'df.applymap(type)'.

Comment: @rmahesh `pandas` does not have a `dtype` that is `str`.  It wraps up string, lists and anything else that isn't a numeric type as `object`.  The individual types underneath can be anything.

Comment: Thank you! That explains why it was coming out as an object.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure why you would want to do this, but here's how:

```
object_columns = (df.dtypes == numpy.object)
df.loc[:, object_columns] = df.loc[:, object_columns].astype(str)
```

If you ever use a loop in Pandas, you are 99% surely doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

why you are using`while` ? rather than simply using `for` ?

```
for i in df.columns:
    if df[i].dtype==object:
        df[i]= df[i].astype(str)
```

Comment: When I ran print(df.Name.dtypes), it still came out as an object.

Comment: and if you do want it get you something like `str`, you can run this  `type(df.Name[1])`

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be where I was going wrong.